# Manually adding sources to dependencies in maven projects in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2

I have a maven project loaded in eclipse and would like to debug it. For that I need all the sources of the dependencies. Sadly the repository is not working correctly and eclipse doesn't download all the jars I need as sources.

Is there a way to manually add dependencies as sources? This would be my quick-and-dirty temporary fix, because I don't know how long it will take to repair the repository. I have all the needed jars with source code on my machine, I only need to add them to the current project.

Comment: You could copy or install them into your local Maven repository (/.m2/repository)

Comment: if you have jars on your local(m2) then the project should just work fine trying to fetch it form there.

Comment: That was an easy solution. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments suggest, the best approach is to install dependencies into Maven's local repository (`.m2/repository`). For those unfamiliar with manually adding dependencies, rather than my repeating what someone has already taken the time to write, please refer to [Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).